# Trilogy where humanity lives on another planet and seeks status through a virtual reality game

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is similar to *Ready Player One*, where humanity seeks status and real world riches in a VR game. Differences are that humanity left Earth and are living on a different planet. The game they play is fantasy-based and our main character beats the game by playing a swashbuckler. The sequel introduces a new game where the NPCs think they are real and the game is run by an AI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible [Epic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_(Kostick_novel)) by Conor Kostick.

[image: Epic]

> Generations ago, violence was banned on New Earth. Society is governed and conflicts are resolved in the arena of a fantasy computer game, Epic. Everyone plays. If you win, you have the chance to go to university, get more supplies for your community, and fulfill your dreams; if you lose, your life both in and out of the game is worth nothing.
>
> When Erik, seeking revenge for the unjust treatment of his parents, dares to subvert the rules of Epic, he and his friends find themselves up against with the ultimate masters of the game: the Committee. If Erik and his friends win, they may have the key to destroying Epic's tyranny over New Earth. But if they lose . . .

Erik does play a swashbuckler in the game, and it does take place on a different planet *New Earth*.

Comment: What does that script say in the middle of the book?

Comment: @jxh _finem facere mundo_, which is Latin for _to put an end to the world_.